# Show dates when the given value for a given id was changed

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to check when the address for the given id was changed, and display the date of the change, along with both (old and new) addresses.

Let's assume we have this data:

```
 id address      date
 1  Long Street  2015-09-20
 1  Broad Street 2015-09-30
 1  Nice Road    2016-09-30
 2  Black Road   2016-09-30
 2  White Road   2017-01-01
```

So the output of the query should be:

```
1 Long Street   Broad Street 2015-09-30
1 Broad Street  Nice Road    2016-09-30
2 Black Road    White Road   2017-01-01
```

It's easy to check for which ids the addresses were changed and how many times it happened, but I don't have any clue how to display the result I actually need.

Comment: How do you decide if Broad Street goes before or after Nice Road?

Comment: @jarlh: 2016 was after 2015 :-)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, I feel so stupid now... Time for another cup of coffee is my only excuse.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the date of the previous record using a correlated subquery:

```
select t.id,
       (select t2.address
        from t t2
        where t2.id = t.id and t2.date < t.date
        order by t2.date desc
        limit 1
      ) prev_address,
      t.address, t.date
from t
having prev_address is not null;
```

The use of the `having` clause is a MySQL extension.  It behaves like a `where` clause using column aliases.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem ideally would make use of lead/lag analytic functions.  As MySQL does not support them, one approach would be to simulate them using session variables.

```
SET @address = '';
SET @date = '';

SELECT
    prev_address,
    address,
    date
FROM
(
    SELECT
        id,
        @address AS prev_address,
        @date AS prev_date,
        @address:=address AS address,
        @date:=date AS date
    FROM yourTable
    ORDER BY date
) t
WHERE
    COALESCE(prev_date, date) <> date AND
    prev_address <> '';
```

**Output:**

```
    prev_address    address         date
1   Long Street     Broad Street    2015-09-30 00:00:00
2   Broad Street    Nice Road       2016-09-30 00:00:00
3   Black Road      White Road      2017-01-01 00:00:00
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: The problem is that I'm using Jasper Reports and this library is quite retarded, and I need to write a simple query, without declaring any variables.

Comment: @CorrieSparrow Rats..I spent 20 minutes on this answer.  Maybe Gordon's response will suit your needs.  I added a demo by the way.

Comment: MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `SELECT`.  Assigning a variable in one expression and then using it in another is unsafe.  The warning is quite explicit:  "However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined." (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html).

Comment: @GordonLinoff Could you edit my query and correct it?  If what your comment says be true then there is a lot of misinformation out there about using session variables in MySQL.